# What is the right way to pass a database object from one method to another in a class

Tags: php, mysql, parameter-passing

I need help in understanding the right way to pass an object (MySQL connection) created in one method to another method within the same class.

I am trying to create a database class that loads the connection using a constructor and all other methods, use this connection to perform their respective functions.

While trying to do so I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /database.php on line 44

My code:

```
class database
{ 
    public $mysqli;

    public function __construct($database_server, $database_name, $database_user, $database_pass)
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli($database_server,$database_user, $database_pass, $database_name);

        if ($mysqli->connect_error)
        {
                  die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
        }
        echo "Database connection established successfully.<br>";
        return $this->mysqli;

    }

    public function fetch_data()
    {

        $query = "select * from payment";
        if ($result = $this->mysqli->query($query))
        {

            // fetch associative array
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["id"], $row["status"]);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function __construct($database_server, $database_name, $database_user, $database_pass)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli($database_server,$database_user, $database_pass, $database_name);

    if ($mysqli->connect_error)
    {
              die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Database connection established successfully.<br>";

    // instead of return, just set the local variable to the `mysqli` property.
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli;

}
```

Or

```
public function __construct($database_server, $database_name, $database_user, $database_pass)
{
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($database_server,$database_user, $database_pass, $database_name);

    if ($this->mysqli->connect_error)
    {
       die('Connect Error (' . $this^>mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $this->mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Database connection established successfully.<br>";    
}
```

And `public $mysqli;` will be better to be `protected`.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer mt question. Your code actually helped me rectify my silly mistake. Also, should all functions return a value. So shouldn't I be using

$this->mysqli = $mysqli;
return $this->mysqli;

Is this required? Is this an overkill? I would like to learn the right and correct way to do this.

Comment: @user1675547 No, constructor function should not return a value.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting `$this->mysqli` anywhere, you need to do `$this->mysqli = $mysqli;` instead of `return $this->mysqli` in your construct.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually creating $mysqli as a property of your class.

You need:

```
class database
{

public $mysqli;

public function __construct($database_server, $database_name, $database_user, $database_pass)
{
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($database_server,$database_user, $database_pass, $database_name);

    if ($this->mysqli->connect_error)
    {
              die('Connect Error (' . $this->mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $this->mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Database connection established successfully.<br>";
    return $this->mysqli;

}
```

or

```
class database
{

public $mysqli;

public function __construct($database_server, $database_name, $database_user, $database_pass)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli($database_server,$database_user, $database_pass, $database_name);

    if ($mysqli->connect_error)
    {
              die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Database connection established successfully.<br>";
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    return $this->mysqli;

}
```

Comment: Thank you Liam for helping me out. I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As others already have mentioned you should set the mysqli like this:

```
$this->mysqli = new mysqli($database_server,$database_user, $database_pass, $database_name);
```

I would suggest not to die in the constructor, thats not to the database class to decide but to the user of the database class. Change it like this:

```
class database
{ 
    private $mysqli;
    public $error = false;

    public function __construct($database_server, $database_name, $database_user, $database_pass)
    {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($database_server,$database_user, $database_pass, $database_name);

        if ($mysqli->connect_error)
          $this->error = 'Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);

    }
```

When constructing the database like this `$db = new Database( ... );` you can check the error property and then decide what to do.